# I don't really know what i did but brew doctor is asking me to unbrewed a lot of stuff

Tags: macos, python-2.7

Hello i was trying to install pygame on my mac running el capitan but i got this error https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/284/max-osx-el-capitan-using-the-deprecated after a while of i found this site 
http://zeringue.io/2016/02/26/fixing-pygame-osx.html. 
I don't if this was the problem of something i did but brew doctor was showing me all this results. I look online but i saw some answers that say i should ignore it and others were saying to delete the stuff. Can someone tell me what to do?

```
 $ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.2.4.13.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.2.4.13.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bio.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/camellia.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cast.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cms.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/comp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/crypto.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des_old.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dh.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dtls1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/e_os2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ebcdic.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ec.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdh.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/engine.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/evp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/hmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/idea.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/krb5_asn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/kssl.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/lhash.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md4.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md5.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/mdc2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/modes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/obj_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/objects.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ocsp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslv.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ossl_typ.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs12.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs7.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pqueue.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rand.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc4.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ripemd.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/safestack.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/seed.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/sha.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/srp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/srtp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl23.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl3.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/stack.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/symhacks.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/tls1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ts.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/txt_db.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui_compat.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/whrlpool.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509_vfy.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509v3.h
  /usr/local/include/node/pthread-barrier.h
  /usr/local/include/node/pthread-fixes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/stdint-msvc2008.h
  /usr/local/include/node/tree.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-aix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-bsd.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-darwin.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-errno.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-linux.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-sunos.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-threadpool.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-unix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-win.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-platform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-util.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8config.h
  /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv/cvaux.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv/cvwimage.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv/cxcore.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv/cxmisc.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv/highgui.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv/ml.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/all_indices.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/allocator.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/any.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/autotuned_index.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/composite_index.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/config.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/defines.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/dist.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/dummy.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/dynamic_bitset.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/general.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/ground_truth.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/hdf5.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/heap.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/hierarchical_clustering_index.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/index_testing.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kdtree_index.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kdtree_single_index.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/kmeans_index.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/linear_index.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/logger.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_index.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/lsh_table.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/matrix.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/nn_index.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/object_factory.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/params.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/random.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/result_set.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/sampling.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/saving.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/simplex_downhill.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/flann/timer.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/ios.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/photo/photo_c.h
  /usr/local/include/opencv2/ts/ts_gtest.h

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a
Error: undefined method `revisioni' for #<Class:0x007fc833092308>
Please report this bug:
  http://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting.html
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/sdl_image.rb:6:in `<class:SdlImage>'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/sdl_image.rb:1:in `load_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:25:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:25:in `load_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:42:in `load_formula_from_path'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:97:in `load_file'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:214:in `load_file'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:88:in `klass'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:84:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:208:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:255:in `factory'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:286:in `from_keg'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:269:in `from_rack'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/diagnostic.rb:1022:in `block in check_for_unlinked_but_not_keg_only'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/diagnostic.rb:1019:in `reject'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/diagnostic.rb:1019:in `check_for_unlinked_but_not_keg_only'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:43:in `block in doctor'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:35:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:35:in `doctor'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:94:in `<main>'
```

t

Answer (score 0):

A post on the bug you link appears to have a solid fix for your problem if you're comfortable with a little tinkering:

> [**Justin Rowe 2015-11-19**](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/284/max-osx-el-capitan-using-the-deprecated#comment-23450776):
>   I can confirm that reverting from sdl_image 1.2.12 to version 1.2.10 does fix the graphics glitches. To Install the old version of sdl_image, I changed the name of the existing homebrew formula from `/usr/local/Library/Formula/sdl_image.rb` to `/usr/local/Library/Formula/sdl_image_.rb` (just to back it up). I then made a new formula using
>
> `brew create https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL_image-1.2.10.tar.gz`
>
> Then I changed the contents of the formula that homebrew created to match those of the original formula. I left out the "bottle do" portion, but copied the dependencies, and the install function. Surprisingly this worked without any need for further editing.

Those errors are probably fine (because they say so) and Brew is quite good at correcting whatever terrible things you do to your system *within the directories it creates*. If you're comfortable doing it correctly, backing up `/usr/local/` and removing conflicts to see what works for you can be a fine solution.

Further, and at risk of just causing you a different problem, you may do much better installing pygame in a Linux VM instead (also recommended by some link in the bug).